# How to make api function dynamically in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs/Nextjs and i am fetching data from "comments.js"
in this file right now data is statically displaying,Here is my current data

```
export const books = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Things fall apart",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Fairy tails",
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to know that how can i convert this "static" data to "dynamic"(from server or database/mysql) ?

Comment: As you've mentioned that you're using Next.JS, I would recommend you to read up on Next.JS's API Routes https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction which allow you to serve up data as an API that you could consume using fetch in React AND as for fetching data from database, I would recommend you to look up Mongo https://www.mongodb.com/

Comment: @rand0m Thank you for your reply, as far i know i can use "axios" and can fetch data by "use api url ( get or post method)" but i want to know if i want to use "nextjs Api" then how can i manage/fetch dynamic data instead of static

Comment: I understood what you are after, I still recommend you reading up on API routes. They're similar to what you're doing except for instead of reading data from `comments.js` your data would be served from a json file on an endpoint which would be anything like `http://localhost/api/comments/all` once you're up to that level, you could then uprgade to using a database